# C++: Dynamic memory allocation + vector

Tags: c++, vector

When I try add person to vector it doesn't work + I can't add more than one person. Im pretty new to C++ and I can't figure it out. Sorry for my English :( Thanks for any help/tips. I was searching about it and try a lot of things, but couldnt make it work anyway. What I'm doing wrong or maybe this code is at mess anyway?

```
    class Osoba
    {
    public:
        char *name, *surname, *phone;                               
        Osoba();                                                                
        Osoba(const char *name, const char *surname, const char *phone);        
        ~Osoba();                                                               
    };

    inline Osoba::Osoba(){};

    inline Osoba::Osoba(const char *name, const char *surname, const char *phone)
    {
        Osoba::name = new char[strlen(name) + 10];                                          
        strcpy(Osoba::name, name);                                                          
        Osoba::surname = new char[strlen(surname) + 1];
        strcpy(Osoba::surname, surname);
        Osoba::phone = new char[strlen(phone) + 1];
        strcpy(Osoba::phone, phone);
    }


    inline Osoba::~Osoba()
    {
        delete name;
        delete surname;
        delete phone;
    }


    int main()
    {   
        const char *name2, *surname2, *phone2;
        vector <Osoba> osoba;

                cout << "\n1.-Workers list\n2.-Add person\n3.-Quit";
                char odp;
                do
                {
                    odp = getch();
                    switch (odp)
                    {
                    case '1':
                        cout << "\n\n\nList:\n";
                        for (int i = 0; i < osoba.size(); i++)
                        {
                            cout << endl;
                            cout << "Name: " << osoba[i].name << endl;
                            cout << "Surname: " << osoba[i].surname << endl;
                            cout << "Phone: " << osoba[i].phone << endl;
                        }
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        cout << "\n\nADD PERSON";
                        cout << "\nName: ";
                        string name;
                        cin >> name;
                        name2 = name.c_str();
                        cout << "Surname: ";
                        string surname;
                        cin >> surname;
                        surname2 = surname.c_str();
                        cout << "Phone: ";
                        string phone;
                        cin >> phone;
                        phone2 = phone.c_str();
                        osoba.push_back(Osoba(name2, surname2, phone2));
                        break;
                    }
                } while (odp != '3');

                return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you think you have problems putting objects in vectors, then you should write the smallest working code example that highlights the problem.

Comment: What's the actual error? Also, you have an allocator mismatch - you need to `delete[]` stuff allocated with `new[]`. Also your class is missing copy and move constructors.

Comment: The problem is that you lack a copy constructor (and that your `delete` is missing a `[]`). Why don't you use `std::string` throughout and stop worrying about `char*`?

Comment: To elaborate on @juanchopanza's point, do you still have a problem if `Osoba` contains only `name` (but you do not include the `surname` or `phone`)?  If the problem you are studying can be demonstrated with *one* field of the structure, then why would you be presenting *three* fields?  (Why not a hundred?)  To help think about how to refine questions please see ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center...and note that there is an "EDIT" button to improve your question.

Comment: Read about the "[rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)". Also, when describing a problem, you should actually describe the problem. Did it compile? Did you get an error? What error? Did you get the results you expected? What results did you get? What results did you expect?

Comment: Ok, ok. I will fix question after work. Sorry for the mess. I should read everything about posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing C++, why not doing it the C++ - way

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Osoba
{
public:                               
    Osoba() = default;                                                               
    Osoba(const string& name, const string& surname, const string& phone);
    Osoba(const Osoba&) = default;
    Osoba& operator=(const Osoba&) = default;
    ~Osoba() = default;         

    const string& Name()    const { return name;    }
    const string& Surname() const { return surname; }
    const string& Phone()   const { return phone;   }

    void Name(const string& n)    { name    =n; }
    void Surname(const string& s) { surname =s; }
    void Phone(const string& p)   { phone   =p; }

private:
    string name, surname, phone;                                          
};

Osoba::Osoba(const string& name, const string& surname, const string& phone)
    : name(name), surname(surname), phone(phone)
{
}
```

Comment: Your getters should be const. They can return a const reference.

Comment: You can drop the functions labeled `= default`, and have it compile with all C++ compilers, and not just the latest.

Comment: @JamesKanze the 3 parameter one will suppress the no parameter one

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems:

Define copy constructor as below:

```
Osoba::Osoba(const Osoba& src) {
  if (src.name != NULL) {
    name = new char[strlen(src.name) + 1];                                          
    strcpy(name, src.name);   
  }                                                       
  if (src.surname != NULL) {
    surname = new char[strlen(src.surname ) + 1];                                          
    strcpy(surname , src.surname );   
  }                                                       
  if (src.phone != NULL) {
    phone = new char[strlen(src.phone) + 1];                                          
    strcpy(phone, src.phone);   
  }                                                       
}
```

Change constructors as below:

```
Osoba::Osoba(){
    name = (char *) NULL;
    surname = (char *) NULL;;
    phone = (char *) NULL;
  }                                   
};

Osoba::Osoba(const char *name, const char *surname, const char *phone)
{
  if (name != NULL) {
    this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];                                          
    strcpy(this->name, name);   
  }                                                       
  if (surname != NULL) {
    this->surname = new char[strlen(surname ) + 1];                                          
    strcpy(this->surname , surname );   
  }                                                       
  if (phone != NULL) {
    this->phone = new char[strlen(phone) + 1];                                          
    strcpy(this->phone, phone);   
  }
}
```

Also, assignment operator:

```
Osoba& Osoba::operatoe = (const Osoba& src) {
  if (this == &src)
    return *this;
  if (src.name != NULL) {
    name = new char[strlen(src.name) + 1];                                          
    strcpy(name, src.name);   
  }                                                       
  if (src.surname != NULL) {
    surname = new char[strlen(src.surname ) + 1];                                          
    strcpy(surname , src.surname );   
  }                                                       
  if (src.phone != NULL) {
    phone = new char[strlen(src.phone) + 1];                                          
    strcpy(phone, src.phone);   
  }
  return *this;                                         
}
```

Comment: Still broken.  What happens if one of the `new` fail?

Comment: And he also needs an assignment operator.

Comment: @JamesKanze try with the edited ans, new generally does not fail, unless you exhaust the heap

Comment: It's still not exception safe.  The heap is a finite resource, and you shouldn't leak memory if `new` fails.

Comment: shouldn't copy-constructor clear members if they are not set in `src`